# How can I use the CanPlaceOn tag on a mob drop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an adventure map in 1.9 and while I know exactly how `CanPlaceOn`
works, I want to know how I can edit a drop of a mob which has a `CanPlaceOn` tag in it.

Example: I want to spawn a zombie which drops a lever or a button that can only be placed on certain blocks. Ive been messing with codes already and I cant seem to spawn a zombie which drops a lever with the `CanPlaceOn` tag in it.

Comment: can you use the entity data to modify the dropped lever

Comment: @HarounMohamed-Fakier possible, but fairly complicated. You'd have to track the mob, check if it died, and then apply entitydata at its position.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a loot table

The best way to do this is using custom loot tables and the `set_nbt` function. The following loot_table makes a mob drop a single lever that can be placed on diamond blocks.

```
{
    "pools":[
        {
            "rolls":1,
            "entries":[
                {
                    "type":"item",
                    "name":"minecraft:lever",
                    "weight":1,
                    "functions":[
                        {
                            "function":"set_nbt",
                            "tag":"{CanPlaceOn:[\"minecraft:diamond_block\"]}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Loot tables](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table) look fairly complicated, but that's because they are extremely powerful and versatile (take a look at the [default dungeon chest loot table](http://pastebin.com/57knFhAQ) for example). Luckily, you can find loot table generators like [this one by MrPingouin](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPingouin/125mx5r5/embedded/result/) on the web.

What happens here is that there is only one category of items (a "pool"), from which 1 item is randomly chosen ("rolls"). The pool only contains a single item ("entry"), which is our lever. The `set_nbt` function is used to set the NBT data of the lever to include the `CanPlaceOn` tag, set to diamond blocks.

Once you have generated your loot table, download it and save it in `<map folder>/data/loot_tables/<some folder>/<some name>.json`.

To use it in the game, you can use the `DeathLootTable` data tag in your summon command, e.g.

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {DeathLootTable:"<some folder>:<some name>"}
```

Comment: For a feature-complete generator, though not nearly as visually pleasing/friendly, there is [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPingouin/125mx5r5/embedded/result/) from [MrPingouin1](http://www.minecraftforum.net/members/MrPingouin1) (which includes the new `limit` tag for the `looting_enchant` function from 1.10). The mincraft.tools generator is outdated and missing a large amount of features, including major ones such as multiple pools.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do a loot table, you can use a command to choose what the mob drops.

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"ZombieNameHere",CustomNameVisible:1,IsVillager:0,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:leather_helmet,Count:1,tag:{Unbreakable:1}}],HandItems:[{id:lever,Count:1,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_block"],display:{Name:"LeverNameHere",Lore:[LeverLoreHere]}}},{}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F],HandDropChances:[1.0F,0.085F],PersistenceRequired:1} I also gave him a helmet just in case
```